# Laravel Chumper Zipper close() not creating zip file

Tags: php, laravel, file, zip, php-ziparchive

I am trying to create a zip file with folders inside it.
Now the code is :

```
{
$zipper = new \Chumper\Zipper\Zipper;
$zipper->make(storage_path('app/' . $zipPath));
.
.
Storage::makeDirectory($zipPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $user->username , 0777);
$zipper->folder($zipPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $user->username);
$currentZipPath = $zipPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $user->username;
Storage::makeDirectory($currentZipPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $myfolder->name , 0777);
                        $zipper->folder($currentZipPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $myfolder->name);
.
.
$this->addDataToZip($contents, $currentZipPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $myfolder->name,  $zipper, $user);

Log::info('Zip status : ' . $zipper->getStatus());  //Gives "No error"
$zipper->close();
}


public function addDataToZip($contents, $path, &$zipper, $user)
 {



foreach ($contents as $content) {
 $filebasepath = storage_path('app/' . $path);

 Storage::copy(
      $this->model->getActiveStorageBasePath($user)
             . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $content->unique_name,
      $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $content->unique_name
 );

$zipper->add(storage_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'app'
                    . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $path
                    . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $content->unique_name);
}
}
```

Now when I view the folder locally, the entie admin.zip folder is created with complete heirarchy and content.
But on $zipper->close, the zip file is not  created and the admin.zip folder remains there.
Also there is no error in the API call or the logs.
Please guide on where I might be making an error

Answer (score 0):

See with example [Chumper/Zipper](https://github.com/Chumper/Zipper). This is the simple and straightforward way to use.

OR you can place this line `"status ::". $zipper->status . "\n"` after `$zipper->add()` to check status.

Comment: Getting : $status not found. And for $zipper->getStatus(), [2016-12-09 12:05:19] local.INFO: status ::No error , for each $zipper->add

Comment: Check this path is proper OR not? `print storage_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $content->unique_name;`

Comment: It shows correct path... the actual absolute path of the original file